# Connecting two Rohm KX224 sensors over I2C

Tags: i2c

I would like to connect two identical sensors (slaves) over an I2C bus. The problem is that they have the same address.

The datasheet says the following:

> The KX224 Slave Address is comprised of a user programmable part, a factory programmable part, and a fixed part, which allows for connection of multiple accelerometers to the same I2C bus. The Slave Address associated with the KX224 is 00111YX, where the user programmable bit X, is determined by the assignment of ADDR (pin 1) to GND or IO_VDD.

Pin 1 is VDD, not ADDR. Also, there is a diagram:

[image: Multiple KX224 Accelerometers on a Shared I2C Bus]

<sub>Multiple KX224 accelerometers on a shared I2C bus</sub>

There are assumptions on the diagram about connecting ground or power, which I am not sure about. Here is the [link](https://docs.rs-online.com/aa86/0900766b816215b7.pdf) to the datasheet.

Do I just need to invert polarity when connecting one of the sensors to instantiate a different address?

Here is what the sensor looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://kionixfs.azureedge.net/en/datasheet/KX224-1053-Specifications-Rev-2.0.pdf) datasheet, the Y part of the address is factory programmed to 1. Pin 7 (SDO/ADDR) is connected to either IO_Vdd or GND to select the X part of the address.

As the table on Page 18 illustrates (and as you might expect), a low on the SDO/ADDR pin results in X = 0 and a high results in X = 1.

You must keep the nCS input input at IO_Vdd in order to select I2C communication and to avoid having the SDO output attempt to drive the aforementioned ADDR pin.

To use two chips on a single I2C interface, simply hard-wire the SDO/ADDR pin on one to GND and the other to IO_Vdd.

---

Okay, as the story in the comments go, we are actually talking aboot a chip on a daughterboard that is intended to plug into a master evaluation board. I have found the [schematic](https://www.rohm.co.jp/sensor-shield-support/accelerometer) of the daughterboard:

You will see that JP1 needs to have the center pad shorted to the top for one address and to the bottom for the other. A guess would be that top is for '1' and bottom is for '0' but I don't see anything that confirms that.

nCS is hard-wired to Vdd, so you don't need to worry about that. R2 and R3 are not installed in your photo.

All you need to do to use this is

1. Install the jumper for the address- you **must** install one or the other position- there is no pullup or pulldown resistor. If you short all 3 together it will short out the power supply which would be bad.
2. Vdd and GND connections
3. SCL and SDA to your processor (there must be I2C pullup resistors installed *somewhere*, if they are not on your MCU board then you can install them in R1/R2 positions).
4. INT output to MCU interrupt input if you want to use it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, probably the answer makes sense for electrical engineers.  However, it is not clear how to relate you answer to the physical pins. Could you please use the annotations of physical pins of KX224: VDD, GND, SDA, SCL, INT1? Also, there are 5 pins in total - pin 7 does not exist in KX224-I2C-EVK-001.

Comment: Please provide a link to a datasheet for your particular chip. EVK sounds like an evaluation board, not an IC.

Comment: https://docs.rs-online.com/aa86/0900766b816215b7.pdf - here is the link. I purchased it via RS components. It is only the accelerometer with the 5 pins, not the evaluation board

Comment: On page 14 you can see the pin functions. There are 16 pins, of which 5 are NC. Pin 7 is the address pin.

Comment: I have added an image of the sensor - there are 5 pins. I have no idea why datasheet says it is 16:(

Comment: That is a photo of an unpopulated PCB, not the sensor. The sensor should be where the U1 is. It won't do anything because it's a blank PCB with no parts installed.

Comment: This looks like a breakout board for the sensor chip. Probably the solder jumper JP1 lets you choose between two addresses. To get four, you'd need to check if you can order the breakout board in the two factory-set variants. If not, look into using two I2C buses or an I2C multiplexer.

Comment: Btw, that photo you added is NOT the sensor. It is indeed the evaluation board. The sensor is the chip marked U1.

Comment: Part of the confusion is that there are three things, the chip (which is the only thing described on the datasheets linked above), the daughterboard (an unpopulated one is in your photo) and there is a much bigger evaluation motherboard. I don't see a schematic of the daughterboard online. Most likely you jump the top or bottom two pins of the three JP1 to select the address, R2 and R3 are pullups for SCL/SDA (not required if they are provided elsewhere).

Comment: right, my bad with the image - fixed it. I have the board with the sensor on it:) Thanks, I will look into what jumper does.

Comment: On the circuit diagram IO_VDD is wired to VDD and INT1 has no connection with ADDR. I am confused here. I want to change the address by only operating on the 5 evaluation board pins. Is that possible? I am able to collect the data already, so no problem with connectivity. Just need to change the address to connect the second accelerometer...

Comment: No it is not possible. A soldering iron is required to add the jumpers.